# MongoDB C# Driver multiple Eq field query

Tags: mongodb-query

Using the MongoDB C# driver How can I include more than one field in the Eq query. With one EQ it works. I am trying something like below but no luck

```
filter= filterBuilder.Eq(entity => entity.id== id) & (entity => entity.Name, name);
 return await dbCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include more than one field in an equality (Eq) query using the MongoDB C# driver, you can use the & operator to combine multiple Eq expressions into a single filter expression.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to include two fields (id and Name) in the Eq query

```
var filterBuilder = Builders<Entity>.Filter;
var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(entity => entity.id, id) & filterBuilder.Eq(entity => entity.Name, name);

return await dbCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```